# How to import text file in Data bricks

Tags: python-3.x, databricks, aws-databricks, databricks-community-edition

I am trying to write text file with some text and loading same text file in data-bricks but i am getting error

Code

```
#write a file to DBFS using Python I/O APIs
with open("/dbfs/FileStore/tables/test_dbfs.txt", 'w') as f:
  f.write("Apache Spark is awesome!\n")
  f.write("End of example!")

# read the file
with open("/dbfs/tmp/test_dbfs.txt", "r") as f_read:
  for line in f_read:
    print(line)
```

Error
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dbfs/FileStore/tables/test_dbfs.txt'

Comment: are you using community edition?

Comment: Yes I am using Community edition   sqlContext.read.text("/FileStore/tables/Suneel/sample1.txt") it's working fine when in use open with it's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/dbfs` mount doesn't work on Community Edition with DBR >= 7.x - it's a known limitation.

To workaround this limitation you need to work with files on the driver node and upload or download files using the `dbutils.fs.cp` command ([docs](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-utils.html)).  So your writing will look as following:

```py
#write a file to local filesystem using Python I/O APIs
with open("'file:/tmp/local-path'", 'w') as f:
  f.write("Apache Spark is awesome!\n")
  f.write("End of example!")
# upload file to DBFS
dbutils.fs.cp('file:/tmp/local-path', 'dbfs:/FileStore/tables/test_dbfs.txt')
```

and reading from DBFS will look as following:

```py
# copy file from DBFS to local file_system
dbutils.fs.cp('dbfs:/tmp/test_dbfs.txt', 'file:/tmp/local-path')
# read the file locally
with open("/tmp/local-path", "r") as f_read:
  for line in f_read:
    print(line)
```

Comment: i tried to copy files from dbfs to local paths but files are not copying if i copy files from dbfs to dbfs it's working see my below code dbutils.fs.cp('dbfs:/FileStore/tables/Suneel/text files/sample1.txt', '/databricks/driver/Suneel/sample1.txt')

Comment: Now It' working fine. I just changed dbutils.fs.cp('dbfs:/FileStore/tables/Suneel/text files/sample1.txt', '/databricks/driver/Suneel/sample1.txt') to dbutils.fs.cp('dbfs:/FileStore/tables/Suneel/text files/sample1.txt', 'file:/databricks/driver/Suneel/sample1.txt')                                                            Thank You Alex Ott

Comment: yes, the `file:/` prefix is important - without it it will continue to use DBFS